# Reformatting a FAT32 and EXT2 partitioned microSD card

Tags: windows, micro-sd-card

So the story is: Link2SD, which required partitioning of my SD card into a FAT32 and EXT2 format, seems to have failed me, giving random deletions of Android apps. I got tired of this and tried to reformat my SD card--especially because my Evo 128GB SD card was unable to be written to by BitTorrent Sync (this never happened before and is not a system error due to Android.)

But this is not an Android question. I just want to format my microSD card.

I then tried using DISKPART in my Windows machine to CLEAN it after EaseUS Partition Manager failed to do the same. The command successfully completed in DISKPART but everything remained the same. EaseUS gave an error message

Anyway, DISKPART CLEAN command isn't working, even after using ATTR DISK CLEAR READONLY. It doesn't give any error message. It just says "DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk." (Yes, I have made sure to SELECT DISK #.)

I tried to pure FORMAT it (both partitions) which does absolutely nothing. All the data is still untouched.

Any other ideas how to reset this microSD?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what device you are using that requires FAT32 or EXT2.  Stick with the exFAT format if you can - is my advice.

The tools on the Windows operating system are not specialized enough to format micro SD cards.  If you EVER get a message asking or telling you to format using Windows DONT DO IT!

The reason is that micro SD cards have two different areas on them when they come from the factory and/or when formatted properly.

There is the storage area, of course, for all the files that you store on it and that are visible when examining the folder contents, but there is also another small administrative area that contains a security information specific to the card.

When the clumsy Windows formatting is employed to format a micro SD it bulldozes across the security area and that important information is lost from the SD card. This loss often throws one of many possible errors when the card is in use, or when you try to plug it in somewhere.

Do not freak out just yet.  Just get organized to recover the card:

1. Never pull a micro SD card out of a device without "unmounting" the micro SD card first.  You can do this on phones and tablets by going to the settings setting on the device and selecting the storage option.  Under Storage select "unmounts" and wait a second for it to go gray.  Without screwing around go to the "All Running Apps" selection (mine is a little square on the bottom ribbon of the home page) and hit "close all apps."  Turn off the device completely through the normal shut-down process.  Always insert micro SD cards when the device is powered OFF.  ALWAYS remove them UNMOUNTED and with the Power OFF.
2. Download the free SD Formatter software and the user guide from the SD Foundation website.  This is the ONLY correct software for formatting micro SD cards.  I used this URL: https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/ to get my copy.  Browse around the site, you can learn a lot about SD standard.  This makes it Sooo easy.
3. I run the software on my Windows 7 computer with the micro SD in a USB converter.  Occasionally I might get the error that it is not ready to work or something so I gently pull the USB out and push it back in while the program is running.  Select the CORRECT drive from the dropdown and press format. Several warnings will pop up reminding you to check that you selected the right "drive".  Check the size information and make sure it is your SD card.
4. Enjoy your reformatted micro SD card.  Total cost: $0.00, nada. Micro SD cards are really volatile if you are fiddling around with them outside a "mounted" environment inside the phone or tablet.

I learned all this fiddling around with my new 1024GB (yes folks, 1TB), no, it is not a smaller chip programmed to read large by a device that deletes your information when you get to the "real" capacity of the chip.  There are also 512GB and 256GB chips out there if you have a friend at the FAB.

It is weird to think that a tiny chip the size of your fingernail holds 1TB. I must be getting old. I think I must have bought twenty different hard drives (the spinning disk type) over the years before I ever purchased one that held even 1 terabyte.

A 2TB micro SD chip is on the horizon. 2TB is the maximum supported capacity that the SDXC format will support.

Comment: Thanks for all this valuable information. I will format it this way from now on... for some reason the drive did not even show up so I would not have been able to format it using the SDcard utility you indicated here. Anyway, I have had the sd card replaced via the warranty anyway now... will definitely use the SDCard utility you showed here...
So how did you get your hands on that 1TB? I sure would like one (without burning my paycheck)

Answer (score 0):

"Formatting" usually affects just a single partition's content, it will not delete partitions themselves.

You can boot a Linux CD ([1](http://gparted.org/), [2](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop)) and use either GParted or `fdisk` to delete partitions (or recreate the whole partition table).

Or you can use a [hex editor](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to blank out the first several blocks of the SD card where the partition table resides (0th block is enough to wipe the MBR; a bit more difficult with GPT), afterwards Windows will re-create a blank partition table.

Comment: I tried the hex editor and 0ed out the entire 0th block (which included some message about NT LDR missing Disk error). Nothing happens and the writing that was originally in the hex just comes back (I ran hex editor as admin and not read-only).

Comment: Did you click "save"? It could also be that the SD card is actually _broken_ and rejects all writes completely...

Comment: Yes i clicked save (through the warning that there is no backup). And yes you are correct i am unable to add any files nor remove files. **It gives the illusion that it works at first** but after reinserting the card, it resets back to exactly the way it was before.

Comment: Is there a quick way to load the GParted on a windows 8 / 10 machine? I am unable to get my computer to boot the GParted Live CD and I want to try and see if maybe the issue is the 2nd partition which is EXT2

Comment: Then the card is just broken. (The second partition _cannot_ have effects like this. There's no "magically revert changes" option.)